How to compute this limit in a shorter time?
Suppose we want to compute the following limit:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor 1.0101\left(\lceil 6r^2 \pi/{\varepsilon}\rceil-1\right)+1\rfloor}{ \lceil 6r^2 \pi/{\varepsilon}\rceil}
\end{equation}
I tried the following code:
Clear["Global`*"]
Limit[Floor[1.0101 (Ceiling[(6 (r^2) Pi)/eps] - 1) + 1]/
  Ceiling[(6 (r^2) Pi)/eps], {eps -> 0, r -> Infinity}]

However, the output takes too long to compute. (Infact, the ouput returns the input rather than a number.)
Note, if we take:
Lim[eps_,r_]:=Lim[eps,r]=Floor[1.0101 (Ceiling[(6 (r^2) Pi)/eps] - 1) + 1]/
 Ceiling[(6 (r^2) Pi)/eps]

and the table of values for plot:
Plot[N[Lim[.00001, x]], {x, 0, 10000}, PlotPoints -> 10000]

should give:

Since the ouputs are extremely close to 1.0101, it seems:
\begin{equation}
\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\lim_{r\to\infty}\frac{\lfloor 1.0101\left(\lceil 6r^2 \pi/{\varepsilon}\rceil-1\right)+1\rfloor}{ \lceil 6r^2 \pi/{\varepsilon}\rceil}=1.0101
\end{equation}
Am I correct? If so, how do we compute this limit in a shorter time?

What is known about asymptotic of r^2/eps?

@UlrichNeumann Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean? If eps approaches zero and r approaches infinity, I don't see how r^2/eps could have a reasonable asymptotic.

Clear["Global*"]
Limit[Floor[1.0101 (Ceiling[u] - 1) + 1]/Ceiling[u], u -> Infinity]

@Cesareo I understand now. Thank You.

Should I delete this post.

No, you need not do it: the @Cesareo's approach is light-weighted (see my answer).

@Arbuja In your limit you only have r^2/eps term. Obviously you know/assume r^2/eps->Infinity. If yes Limit[Floor[const (Ceiling[(6   Pi) u] - 1) + 1]/Ceiling[(6   Pi) u] ,   u -> Infinity] evaluates to const if const>0

Another way:
func = Floor[A* (Ceiling[(6 (r^2) Pi)/eps] - 1) + 1]/Ceiling[(6 (r^2) Pi)/eps] /. r -> 1/r /. eps -> r;

(*Where: A = 1.0101*)

Limit[func, r -> 0, Assumptions -> A > 0]

(* A *)


Nice answer. My similar comment was some seconds to late ;-)

This is a wrong way because of eps -> r.  In the expression  Floor[A* (Ceiling[(6 (r^2) Pi)/eps] - 1) + 1]/Ceiling[(6 (r^2) Pi)/eps] eps is a variable, not depending on a variable  r.

@user64494 If is wrong why gives a correct answer?

@MariuszIwaniuk:  As stated in my answer, the double limit exists and the iterated limit equals that double limit.  Putting eps->r, you find the limit along the certain curve which also equals the doble limit,. That limit along the certain curve is not related to the iterated limit under consideration. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Both A and  the substitution r->1/r  are made to confuse the reader. Hope I am clear.

All that is described in the Wiki article linked in my answer. Especially pay your attention to "For such a multivariable limit to exist, this definition requires the value of f approaches L along every possible path approaching (p, q)".

The iterated limit equals the double limit if the latter exists. Also in order  to be accurate, 1.0101 should be replaced by Rationalize[1.0101,0].
Limit[Floor[Rationalize[1.0101, 0]* (Ceiling[(6 (r^2) Pi)/eps] - 1) + 1]/
Ceiling[(6 (r^2) Pi)/eps], {eps, r} -> {0, Infinity}]


10101/10000

To ground the @Cesareo's approach, the theorem about the limit of composition should be used (see, for example, Wiki for info).

BTW, Limit[1.1*x]/x, x -> 0] returns 1.1. This makes no sense in traditional math and should be treated as a bug.

What is the bug (other than the syntax issue)?

@DanielLichtblau: Sorry, it should be Limit[Sin[1.1*x]/x, x -> 0] in my comment. The input should be returned: Limit deals with exact numbers only.

@user64494 What? Sin x and x are just canceled out and 1.1 remains. I  learned this cheating method very fast. Maybe more obvious for you if Sin (12 x)/x is used. The graph shows that at 0 it goes close to 12.

@ВалерийЗаподовников:  Can you ground  your claim "Sin x and x are just canceled out and 1.1 remains"?

@The down-voter: What is wrong in my anser? To down vote without any explanation is not fair.

Limit does a reasonable job when given approximate input. (Yes, I’m allowed to make that claim.) I didn’t downvote, but the claim made in the comments is…short on grounding.

@DanielLichtblau: Can you give a reference which confirms your personal opinion "Limit does a reasonable job when given approximate input"?

@DanielLichtblau: Indeed, Mathematica treats decimals as exact numbers: 1.4 == 140/100 performs True.

(i) That they are deemed Equal is not tantamount to treating decimals as exact. (ii) You are making claims about the software that are not well informed. No rule against that, but it’s sort of a disservice to the forum. (I think I’m in a decent mood today, but admit my comments might seem otherwise.)

As for that reference, it’s (obviously) myself. I have put decades into making these functions behave. Yes,  sometimes they do things that surprise me, not necessarily in a good way. That’s the nature of the beast. And it does not happen often, excluding areas where we do not have the needed mathematical knowledge e.g. elliptics branch cuts or hypergeometrics with the variable of interest appearing in multiple parameter slots.

@user64494 They are canceled because they grow the same way. As you know this is explained later in calculus with ~ symbol. They are equvivalent infinitisimals, as x goes to zero at 0 and sin x goes to zero at 0.

@DanielLichtblau It is well understood that Limit of Sin (a x)/x at 0 is a. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2584328/why-can-we-replace-an-infinitesimal-in-a-limit-with-an-equivalent-infinitesimal/2584375#comment5334797_2584375

Mathematically 1.1 is the same exact number as 11/10 written just in a different form. The fact that computers treat 1.0 not exactly same as 1 is a different matter. The number 3.14 is the same exact number as 314/100 but they are both inexact in describing value of π. Down-voters may be simply down-voting your comment about "traditional math" because some comments may degrade value of otherwise innocent answer. But this is just my guess about the reason of down-voting.

@ВалерийЗаподовников I don’t think I implied otherwise about that sine limit. But there are so many comments it’s difficult to sort through them.

@DanielLichtblau I see. He argues that your 1.1 is not the same as rationalize of 1.1. But it is, right? 1.1 is infinite precision in wolfram, it is just that as a decimal it triggers floating math in functions afterwards. Anyhow, floating 1.1 would be best answer here anyway.

1.1 actually is represented as a machine double. So it is not infinite precision.
